# ggplot date formatting overlaps with small data frames

Tags: r, ggplot2

Formatting of dates is problematic in ggplot2 when there are only 2 rows in a data frame:

```
> dt <- Sys.Date() - 0:1
> dt
[1] "2013-11-14" "2013-11-13"
> vals <- 0:1
> df <- data.frame(dt, vals)
> df
          dt vals
1 2013-11-14    0
2 2013-11-13    1
> class(df[, 1])
[1] "Date"
> class(df[, 2])
[1] "integer"
> g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = dt, y = vals)) + geom_line()
> plot(g)
```

[image]

See how the x axis date labels have gone weird.

Yet this works fine:

```
> dt <- Sys.Date() - 0:9
> vals <- 0:9
> df <- data.frame(dt, vals)
> df
           dt vals
1  2013-11-14    0
2  2013-11-13    1
3  2013-11-12    2
4  2013-11-11    3
5  2013-11-10    4
6  2013-11-09    5
7  2013-11-08    6
8  2013-11-07    7
9  2013-11-06    8
10 2013-11-05    9
> g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = dt, y = vals)) + geom_line()
> plot(g)
```

[image]

In the bad version looks like it's overwriting the hours twice of something. I guess I could suppress the time component (somehow) but is there a way of avoiding tinkering with the x axis labels altogether and still have it work properly for small data frames?

Comment: This looks like a problem in `ggplot2`. Why don't you [file an issue](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues?state=open)?

Comment: There is https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/797 which seems to be the same issue.

Comment: this is a really problematic area, even if this bug seems rare and isolated as ggplot usually does an excellent job. Some of the new browser-based packages via rcharts also have similar issues. Axis range selection and number formatting is one of the toughest aspects of chart programming (anyone use Excel - terrible) and one where, admirably, base graphics gets it right most of the time. Along with speed, this is a big reason not to chuck base graphics out the window, though to be fair, ggplot2 axis training is to me the huge benefit of this package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that this is some bug. But solution would be to add `scale_x_date()` and then use `date_format()` from library `scales` to set labels as you need.

```
library(scales)
ggplot(df, aes(x = dt, y = vals)) + geom_line()+
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%b %d"))
```

[image]

Comment: Works... but I will now have to make sure I don't need years on the x axis. Guess here we go with the if statements.....

Comment: You can make the labels as you want, for example, this will include also year scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%Y %b %d")).

Comment: Understood but I want the labels to be as concise as possible, not including the year if there are only a small number of points. Base graphics under xts would do that no problemo. My charts range from 1-2 days up to 2-3 years, and they change at runtime. Not a problem, a few if statements will do what you say above. Thank you.